# Navbar positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

I am making a navigation bar on the top of my website. I set the position to fixed, but this isn't working so well because I'm using absolute positioning and if the browser page is too small then the navigation bar will stay fixed while you can't see all of it.

In other words, does anyone know how to make a jQuery system where instead of setting the positioning to fixed you make the px from top change based off of how much the user has scrolled? I basically need a jQuery alternative to fixed positioning.

That was kind of lengthy...

Comment: [`$(window).scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) is what you're looking for

Comment: Robiseb. How would I use it?